# PDO sets server response code?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm making an ajax query to a framework that we use.  I am unable to set the server response code except by setting it where the PDO execute method is called.

The pattern works like this:

An ajax query runs, posting to a file, action.php, that validates inputs.  If inputs are valid, we call a function in the business logic (application.php), which then calls the underlying PDO insert/save method.  If we get a good save, we return TRUE in our action.php function.

In my ajax call, I have a .done() function that confirms the save took place by checking xhr.status.  I want to set xhr.status to 201 when we have a successful save, by calling http_response_code(201);.  This works if I actually do so in the PDO layer, right after the execute() method, but I can't get it to work anywhere else.  Obviously, that is not the right place to set a response code.

Sorry the question is so abstract.  Here is a little example of the code that isn't working:

```
            $resInfo = new ResInfo();

    if($resInfo = saveResident()){
        http_response_code(201);
    }

    return true;
```

The response code is not set here.  Instead, it is set in the PDO  method that saveResident() calls.

Anyone else ever have a similar issue?

EDIT:

I realized that saveResident() returns a copy of the saved object rather than a boolean, so I needed to separate the call to it from persisting the saved object:

```
    if(saveResident()){
        $resInfo = saveResident();
        http_response_code(201);
    }
```

Comment: Why you use assignement sign `=` `$resInfo = saveResident()` instead of equal sign: `==`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$resInfo->saveResident()`?

Comment: Sorry guys.  There's a of code left out, as it was just too much to include.  @Christian Bitoi, because I am actually calling the function there, and want $resInfo to be set to its return value.

saveResident() is a business logic level method that calls the setters of the ResInfo object, passing in sanitized $_POST values, then calls down to the PDO layer that writes the objects properties into the appropriate database fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say:

- it works within `saveResident()`
- `saveResident()` runs successfully.
- And not right after in that if statement.

I would guess that saveResident returns false, an empty array or nothing at all. `$resInfo` is not used after all.

Comment: So you put me on the right track.  Rather than a boolean, saveResident() returns a copy of the saved object.  

I just needed to separate the save call and the part where I persist it:

$resInfo = new ResInfo();
     if(saveResident()){
    $resInfo = saveResident();
    http_response_code(201);
        }